# Why (and how) did my artillerists just march away from their guns, in good order?

Tags: napoleon-total-war

Playing Napoleon Total War (SP), Battle of Arcole on Very Hard, my two 12lb batteries unlimbered immediately in their start positions targeting the enemy 12 lb'ers in Arcole. Having a little better luck than usual, they destroyed the Austrian battery before I had finished destroying the first of Alvinczi's relieving Grenzer battalion. Then the whole lot of them simply marched away from their guns, in good order, to join the rest of Napoleon's force!?!

Does anyone know how and why this happened? When I inspect the gun site all 8 guns are lined up in good order and shape, though the limbers are missing. No artillerist casualties were incurred.

Did I somehow command them to do this with a shortcut command? I cannot think of a command that would do this, but I am new to the game.

FYI: I targeted the ground just behind the second Austrian gun, counting from the North.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can order to them to abandon their guns, and they'll do it themselves if they rout or run out of ammo. If they haven't run of ammo you should be able order them to take back their guns.

Comment: @RossRidge: Okay; I didn't try that. However the limbers disappeared, any idea how that happened?

Comment: Apparently I'm getting the Total War games confused. It appears in Napoleon units have unlimited ammo, and I can't find a way of ordering an artillery unit to drop its guns. Even withdrawing results in the unit taking its artillery with it. Routing is the only way I can see how a unit could be separated from its guns. In that case the limbers (slowly) withdraw on their own. If the unit recovers they can be ordered back to their guns, but I think the limber is lost for that battle. It might also happen if the unit is engaged in melee but doesn't rout.

Comment: @RossRidge: On VH at least, infantry has finite ammunition (as some of my units have run out), but I can't speak yet for artillery. Thank you for the update - perhaps I stumbled on a console cheat. I can't see how they could have been in a melee without taking any losses, or some of the guns being destroyed.